# Considering "PointSize[0]" and even $[-1]$ in NumberLinePlot, why those circles still exist?

Tags: plotting

In this code, I put "PointSize[0]" (or [-1])

```
NumberLinePlot[{Sin[x] < 0, Sin[x] >= 0}, {x, 0, 13}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.001], Red, CapForm["Butt"], 
    PointSize[0]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.001], CapForm["Butt"], Black, Opacity[100], 
    PointSize[0]]}]
```

but I get this plot

[image]

As can be seen, those circles still exist (cf. magnified part). How can I get rid of these circles and have only line segments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work-around: Post-process `NumberLinePlot` output to remove `Point`s:

```
NumberLinePlot[{Sin[x] < 0, Sin[x] >= 0}, {x, 3, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.001], Red, CapForm["Butt"] ], 
    Directive[Thickness[0.001], CapForm["Butt"], Black, Opacity[1]]}] /. _Point -> {}
```

[image]

Magnified:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) as an alternative

```
RegionPlot[{
  Sin[x] < 0 && 0 < x < 13 && 1 < y < 1.1,
  Sin[x] >= 0 && 0 < x < 13 && 2 < y < 2.1},
 {x, 0, 13}, {y, 0.8, 2.2},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
 AspectRatio -> 1/10,
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> {True, False},
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]